# How to retrieve value stored in hidden_field_tag in rails 3.1.4 with params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

We define a hidden_field_tag in new.html.erb for invoice controller like this:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :html_content_for_lease_record, '' %>
```

After assigning the new value to `:html_content_for_lease_record` with javascript(we can see the new value in html source page for the hidden field), how can we retrieve the new value from invoice controller? We tried `params[:html_content_for_lease_record]` and it returns nil. Thanks.

Comment: Just checking. The hidden field is inside the form you submit?

Comment: Yes. it is in partial for new.html.erb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it with `hidden_field`

```
<--! note: TWO parameters below -->
<%= hidden_field :html_content_for, :lease_record %>
```

Assign a value via javascript and then to access it from your controller

```
params[:html_content_for][:lease_record]
```

By looking at the output from the terminal that's running your web server you should be able to see all the params being passed to your controller. Based on that you can easily find the param value you need to use.

Comment: I don't quite understand why there need two parameters. I only need one parameter to store a value from another element on the form.

Comment: Since `hidden_field_tag` isn't working for you I'm giving you another alternative to try out. You need two parameters because just how you use `hidden_field`. Try it out. If it doesn't work then something else is causing your problem.

Comment: Didn't work. THe error is:undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass. should be caused by the params.

Comment: Sounds like your problem is somewhere else. Look at the params hash that's being passed to your controller. I describe how in my answer.

Comment: <%= hidden_field :html_content_for_lease_record, params[:html_content_for_lease_record] %> allowed the retrieving the value with params[:html_content_for_lease_record] in controller. There may be better way to do it.